# Why the result of the Macro is different with the function in C

Tags: c, recursion, macros

In the below code, it is used to get the binary tree's height. Take [1,2] as input, if use Macro definition MAX, the result 1 which is not correct. While use the function max, the result 2 which is correct. What causes the difference?

```
  1
 /
2

#define MAX(a,b) a>b?a:b
int max (int a, int b) {
    return a>b?a:b;
}
int maxDepth(struct TreeNode* root){
    if (root == NULL) return 0;
    else {
        int left = maxDepth(root->left);
        int right = maxDepth(root->right);
        return max(left, right) + 1;
        //return MAX(left, right) + 1; // incorrect
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your incorrect expression: `return MAX(left, right) + 1;` will be expanded to:

```
 return left>right?left:right + 1;
```

Adding some parens to clarify the bug:

```
 return (left>right) ? (left) : (right + 1);
```

---

I think you can fix it with:

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a>b)?(a):(b))
```

But be wary!  Even this will not work for ALL situations, due to double-evaluation of macro parameters!

Macros are bad news.

---

P.S. Roberto asked for an example where the macro still won't work:

Basically, anytime a statement has a side-effect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX(a,b) ((a>b)?(a):(b))
int main(void)
{
    int A = 3;
    int B = 4;
    printf("Bigger value is %d", MAX(2*A++, B) );
    
    printf("A : %d\nB : %d\n", A, B);
    return 0;
}
```

A naive reading would suggest that `2*A++` would be `6`, and leave `A` with value `4` (post-increment).  But, because the expression `2*A++` gets evaluated ***twice*** in the macro, the macro returns `8`, and `A` ends up being `5`, and there is even undefined behavior in the code.

Comment: A. Macros are BAD! B. Macros are GRRRREAT! C. Macros are a useful tool when used properly by developers who are familiar with their uses, limitations, and potential problems. Pick one...

Comment: Could you please make an example in which even the macro with parenthesis would not work?